# Extending an expression<func<t, bool>>

Tags: c#, expression-trees

It has been a long while since I have delved into expression trees and I am struggling with the following problem.

Basically I want to take the following `Expression<Func<T, TIdType>>`:

`(a) => EF.Property<TIdType>(a, "TenantId")`

and extend it to become this `Expression<Func<T, bool>`:

`(a) => EF.Property<TIdType>(a, "TenantId").Equals(TenantId)`

So basically I want to take the original expression and add on `.Equals(TenantId)`

For the background to this issue, its all due to me attempting to workaround an issue in EF Core 2.0 as raised here:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11456

The following hopefully shows what I am attempting in more detail:

```
public class FooEntity
{
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        var adaptor = new TenantFilterExpressionAdaptor<FooEntity, Guid>();
        var tenantIdFilter = adaptor.Adapt((a) => EF.Property<Guid>(a, "TenantId"));

    }
}

public class TenantFilterExpressionAdaptor<T, TIdType>
{

    public TIdType TenantId { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Adapt(Expression<Func<T, TIdType>> idExpression)
    {

        // Tack on .Equals(TenantId) to the expression!?

        // assume I have to add nodes to the body?
        // idExpression.Body?

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to build new expression, because expressions are immutable. In this case you can reuse body and parameters of existing expression for the new one:

```
public class TenantFilterExpressionAdaptor<T, TIdType> {

    public TIdType TenantId { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> Adapt(Expression<Func<T, TIdType>> idExpression) {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(idExpression.Body, Expression.Constant(TenantId)),
            idExpression.Parameters);
    }
}
```

You mentioned in comments that constant is problematic for you. In this case you can reference property itself and not its value:

```
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(idExpression.Body, Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(this), nameof(TenantId))),
    idExpression.Parameters);
```

This will be expression like:

```
x => x.TenantId == this.TenantId
```

where `this` is instance of your adapter.

Comment: Thank you. In that solution, the `Expression.Constant(TenantId)` is problematic for me, as the TenantId value needs to be supplied at runtime (as it changes). Would I need to convert it to a parameter? Any chance of extending your answer to address that for an extra upvote?? :-)

Comment: @Darrell why is it a problem? Are you going to cache that expression somewhere and reuse? Usually that's not a good idea and you build expressions as you need them.

Comment: I know, in this case though its an EF expression that EF caches and reuses. I have no control over that at all.. :-(